# How can the Java Transient fields be de-serialized back to their original values?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

As I understand the transient and static fields of Java Objects are prevented from being serialized by JVM while object is serialized at the source. Once serialized how can these fields be obtained back to their original values while the object is de-serialized at the destination?

Comment: Transient fields have to be recalculated.

Comment: @AndyTurner Could you point me to an example on the internet or any codebase on Github?

Comment: [`HashSet`'s internal map](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashSet.java#l95) is transient. You can see it being constructed in [`readObject`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashSet.java#l326).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can the Java Transient fields be de-serialized back to their original values?

They can't be deserialized: they are, by definition, not included in the serialized representation of the instance.

Instead, they are recalculated.

---

An example of this is the [internal map in `HashSet`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashSet.java#l95). There's no actual need to store the "map-ness" of the contents of the `Set`; there isn't even any need to store the "set-ness" (as in, the fact that there aren't duplicates).

The serialized representation of the `HashSet` is just the elements - it looks a lot like a serialized array - it's just [one object after another](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashSet.java#l285).

```
// From HashSet.writeObject():

// Write out all elements in the proper order.
for (E e : map.keySet())
  s.writeObject(e);
```

When being deserialized, [these objects are read one-by-one](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashSet.java#l333), and put into a `Map`:

```
// From HashSet.readObject():

// Read in all elements in the proper order.
for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    E e = (E) s.readObject();
  map.put(e, PRESENT);
}
```